# Excel 365 - Pivot tables ungroup dates when refreshed; not an issue in Excel 2016

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, powerpivot, microsoft-excel-365

I have an Excel workbook that is pulling data from MS SQL Server into a PowerPivot data model and then about a dozen pivot tables. These tables contain date information that is grouped by year and fiscal quarter as follows:

```
2018
    Qtr1
    Qtr2
    Qtr3
    Qtr4
2019
    Qtr1
    Qtr2
```

In the previous version of Excel everything worked fine, but now that we've upgraded to 365 I started running into issues every time I tried to refresh the data.

After some troubleshooting I determined that Excel is ungrouping the date ranges in each pivot table when they refresh which causes them to overlap and error out. Moving the tables around so that nothing can overlap solves that issue but I am still left with a bunch of pivot tables that are no longer grouped by year/quarter and instead display each individual date on its own line.

I have "[Disable automatic grouping of Date/Time columns in PivotTables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jafcd.png)" unchecked in settings, and have confirmed that the dates are not being treated as strings per [this SU post](https://superuser.com/questions/1125762/excel-pivot-table-does-not-group-dates).

Is this an issue with 365, or am I missing a setting somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of tinkering with the data model / underlying query I ended up just rebuilding the file from scratch. Not sure what got scrambled in the conversion of the old file, but the new file works.